# How to take each array elements in paperJs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, paperjs

```
var path = new Path.Rectangle(new Point(50, 50), new Size(100, 50));
path.style = {
    fillColor: 'white',
    strokeColor: 'black'
};
var copy = {};

//Create a copy of the path and set its stroke color to red:
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

    var copy[i] = path.clone();
    console.log(copy[i]);
    copy[i].strokeColor = 'red';
    //Rotate the copy by 45 degrees:
    copy[i].rotate(45);
}
```

Comment: `copy` is an object not an array

Comment: how can i use copy as an array here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you need to do is to initialize the `copy` as an array;

```
var copy = [];
```